# Navigating whole Page by clicking submit button of a form in a frame

Tags: html, frames

I have 3 frames in a HTML page and there is a form with submit button in a frame. when I hit submit , that corresponding frame is reloaded instead of whole page.
How to make whole page naviate?

Comment: then use ajax for this

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside one of your frame

```
 <input type="Submit" onclick="parent.location.reload();" value="Submit">
```